# About scope and OOP in PHP

Tags: php, oop, variables, scope

I am having trouble understanding how to work with objects.

The specific code:

```
class first{
    class second{
        public function widgets(){
            $a_variable = $a_value;
        }
        #1
    }
    $second = new second;
    #2
}
#3
$first = new first;
```

1. If I initialize `$a_variable` as `$a_variable` it is only available inside the function, correct?
2. If I initialize `$a_varialbe` as `$this->a_variable` it is only available inside class second, correct?
3. Can I initialize `$a_variable` as `$first->second->a_variable`?  If so, How would I call it at `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`?
4. Can I initialize `$a_varialbe as $this->second->a_variable`?  If so, How would I call it at `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`?

As you can see I am simply confused as to how OOP works.

---

First of all, I want to express how much I appreciate all of the help.  I have already learned more than enough to consider this question a smashing success.

That said, even if it is poorly formulated, psuedo-code and invalid syntax, this code DOES run.

```
class class_1{

    public function function_1(){

        require('class_2.php');

        public function function_2_callback(){

            //%%%%%%  How do I set a variable here and get the DATA...

        }

        $this->class_2 = new class_2("function_2_callback");
    }

}

$class_1 = new class_1;

//&&&&&&&&&& Get the DATA here?



/* CONTENTS OF class_2.php */

class class_2($callback){

    call_user_function($callback);

}
```

Even if we have to look at this as an exercise.  Can someone tell me how I would first set (@ %%%%%%%)and then call a variable (@ &&&&&&&&) as shown?

Comment: +1 for effort, but I would urge you to test your code before listing your questions. You could quite easily find the answers to these questions if you tested it yourself, or had a look around the internet at sites such as http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php. Just a pointer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference that I should have easily found myself.. and yet, in my specific situation, I have a very complicated multi_curl class I need to initialize inside of a function that is inside of a class.  The "class inside of a class" runs fine, the problem is, there is I can't access the data within a call_back function which is exactly where that function is in the example.  Specifically, I have a class that is require()'d inside of a function that is inside of a class.

Comment: There is a function that is passed into the second class as a variable of the main class.  The problem is I cannot figure out how to access that variable outside of both classes (@ #3).

Comment: You should probably rethink your way of doing this. Class in class is probably not the way to go, and I'm confused since I've never seen such concept in PHP until now. Could you explain why you need a class to be inside another class?

Comment: It's a Syntax error to nest classes.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help by the way.  So I have a framework class.  It requires other code as it is neede based on circumstances.  Some of this code is quite large.  It is not always needed. I could include it at the global level, i.e. class first{} class second{}, however there are a half dozen 700 line classes that might be needed, but at any given time only say 2 are needed.  I have been dealing with this by requiring the classes directly inside of the class->functions that need them.  That way, the classes are only included if they are needed for that rendering.

Comment: @phant0m, thank you for the help.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Check out www.skateboard-creator.com/back/class_test.php.  Isn't that a nested class without an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: What you have there doesn't work, you cannot declare a class inside a class the way you are doing (notwithstanding conditionally declaring a class inside a function, which you should not do).

Scope in PHP (including OOP) is very simple:

1. variables have function scope
2. object properties are accessible if you have a reference to the object
3. the *visibility* of object properties can be restricted

The only real *scope* you have is function scope for variables:

```
$a = 'foo';

function bar() {
    $a = 'bar';
}
```

The two `$a`s are entirely unrelated, in different scopes. As simple as that.

```
class Foo {

    public $a = 'foo';

    public function bar() {
        $this->a;  // foo

        $a = 'bar';
    }

}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->a;  // foo
```

An object property has no *scope*, it has visibility. You can access it if you have *the object in scope*. Above, `$foo` is the object. It's in scope, its property `a` is `public`, therefore it can be accessed using `$foo->a`. Inside the class, the property is accessible via `$this->a`.

The `$a = 'bar'` is a local variable in the function and has nothing to do with `$this->a`. It is not accessible anywhere except inside the function. Refer to rule #1, function scope.

```
class Bar {

    protected $b = 'bar';

    public function baz() {
        $this->b;  // bar
    }

}

$bar = new Bar;
$bar->b;  // doesn't work
```

If the *visibility* is not `public`, the property (here `b`) is *not accessible* from outside the class itself. Inside the class you can access it using `$this->b`, but not from outside using `$bar->b`. It's not about *scope*, but visibility.

And that's pretty much the scope rules in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT be nesting classes like that. That shouldn't even run. I would suggest running the code first. There are some tools online for testing small snippets of PHP code, such as [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

For the code to run as you might expected it to, it should look like this:

```
class second{
    public function widgets(){
        $a_variable = $a_value;
    }
}

class first{
    public $second;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->second = new second;
    }
}

$first = new first;
```

A variable that begins with $[a-z]+ is local to the function. A property beginning with $this->[a-z]+ (where [a-z] is 1 or more letters) is part of the object.

There's some documentation on php.net that goes over the specifics of objects in php [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

> If I initialize $a_variable as $a_variable it is only available inside
>   the function, correct?

Yes, correct. It begins with $[a-z]. Not quite true if you use the `global` keyword, but that's discouraged.

> If I initialize $a_varialbe as
>   $this->a_variable it is only available inside class second, correct?

Yes, but you should declare it first. You can do this with `public $variable`, `protected $variable` or `private $variable`. `public` means a property can be accesses from the outside, whereas `private` means only the class itself can access it. `protected` is private to the outside, but public to classes that extend from your class.

(`public`/`private`/`public` became available in PHP 5. In PHP 4 you would use `var $variable`, which defaults to public in PHP 5)

> Can I initialize $a_variable as $first->second->a_variable?

You can arbitrarily initialize class variables without declaring them, but that's not something you should be doing.

> If so, How would I call it at #1, #2, and #3?

You can't call code there (in your example). Code must be inside a function or in the global context (outside of the class definition).

Answer (score 2):

### A Brief Explanation of Classes

```
class foo{

    // This can be accessed anywhere
    public $i_am_public;

    // This can be accessed within this class and any sub classes
    protected $i_am_protected;

    // Thi can only be accessed within this class
    private $i_am_private;

    // This function can be accessed anywhere
    public function foo_function(){

        // This variable is only available in this function
        // it cannot be accessed anywhere else
        $variable = 'Hello World';

        // However, you can access any of the other variables listed above
        // like so
        $this->i_am_public = 'public';
        $this->i_am_protected = 'protected';
        $this->i_am_private = 'private';

        // Write these variables
        echo $this->i_am_public;
        echo $this->i_am_protected;
        echo $this->i_am_private;
    }
}

$foo = new foo;

$foo->foo_function();

// You can change any publicly defined variables outside
// of the class instance like so
$foo->i_am_public = 'testing';
```

### Specific Answers to Questions

**Before I go any further, I would hugely urge you not to define a class within a class! Instead, use class extensions which I will explain later. In fact, I am surprised your code even works!**

> If I initialize $a_variable as $a_variable it is only available inside
>   the function, correct?

Yes, this will only be available inside the function. If you want to access it outside of the function then you need to define it outside the function using one of the scope definitions `public, protected, private`.

> If I initialize $a_varialbe as $this->a_variable it is only available
>   inside class second, correct?

This depends on what scope you give it, but you shouldn't be defining a class within a class anyway.

> Can I initialize $a_variable as $first->second->a_variable? If so, How
>   would I call it at #1, #2, and #3?

I cannot answer this as I have never nested a class within a class, once again I would urge you to change this structure.

> Can I initialize $a_varialbe as $this->second->a_variable? If so, How
>   would I call it at #1, #2, and #3?

Please see above answer :-)

### Nesting Classes

As mentioned, I have never seen this before, and I am surprised it even works. You should definitely change this structure.

One suggestions would be to use extensions like so:

```
class foo{

    // This can be accessed anywhere
    public $i_am_public;

    // This can be accessed within this class and any sub classes
    protected $i_am_protected;

    // Thi can only be accessed within this class
    private $i_am_private;

    public function foo_function(){

        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}

class bar extends foo {

    // This is a public function    
    public function baz(){

        // These will work
        $this->i_am_public = 'public';
        $this->i_am_protected = 'protected';

        // This will not work as it is only available to
        // the parent class
        $this->i_am_private = 'private';
    }
}

// This will create a new instance of bar which is an 
// extension of foo. All public variables and functions
// in both classes will work
$bar = new bar;

// This will work because it is public and it is inherited
// from the parent class
$bar->foo_function();

// This will work because it is public
$bar->baz();
```

Comment: Why discourage something you don't know about? That's bad practice.

Comment: @phant0m Because it doesnt work, it is awful code! As everybody else in this post has pointed out aswell

Comment: No, *your* post says you don't know. That's different.

Comment: nesting classes does not work, if you copy the example from the question to a file and run the file you get the parse error thats supposed to be there:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Not true, check out http://www.skateboard-creator.com/back/class_test.php.  I might be misunderstanding, but it seems to me Hello World is echoing.....

Comment: I agree :)  Still don't know how to get my variables out of that mess though :(

Comment: @SamanthaP I didnt see the amendment to your question, I will have a look and see what the issue is. If possible, can you update the question with a clear outline of what you want your code to achieve, this will make my job a lot easier :-)

Comment: Sure! Check Out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471913/more-about-php-oop-classes-within-classes

Answer (score 2):

First of all your example is invalid code
PHP does not support nested classes, meaning a class within a class.

if you define a class, a variable initialized within a method is local to that method, while you can "initialize" an attribute with $this->newattribute, you should have declared it and its visibility before (before you write a method public / private / protected $varname = "initial value";).

Your questions 3 and 4 would make sense in another context, this is when an object is passed as member of another object, see example below.

If you build it like

```
<?php

class First {  
  public $second;
}

class Second {
  public $a_variable;
}

$foo = new First();
$foo->second = new Second();
```

you can access it:

```
$foo->second->a_variable = "foo";
```

or within a method in second with

```
$this->a_variable;
```

or within a method in first with

```
$this->second->a_variable;
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding all of this.  But with a require, a class within a class DOES run.

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)